# Yii2 DbSession lost after redirect, 90% of the time

Tags: yii, yii2

My login worked perfectly with PHP sessions. I tried switching to DbSession engine but login will not work anymore, as the session is empty after the page redirection.

Here's the workflow:

1. User enters his user id and clicks *submit* to post the data
2. Validation works (I tested) and a new *identity cookie* is created with the key *sess* = XXXX (tested with log just before redirect).
3. The $_SESSION is filled with the user data (tested with log just before redirect)
4. The page redirects with the new *response cookie*.
5. The password page loads and the request cookie has the same XXXX value (tested with log just after redirect + in chrome developer tools).
6. The session now only contains

   [__flash] => Array
   (
   )

*response cookie "sess"* = *request cookie "sess"* = *id* in the [session table](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-performance-tuning#optimizing-session), so the same key is everywhere, yet the session is still empty on the password page, 90% of the time (because in some random cases, the session is still there, but I can't reproduce it on demand)

I already checked these questions, not the same problem:
[PHP session lost after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect/17242347)
[Session lost after redirect in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067929/session-lost-after-redirect-in-codeigniter)

Has anyone seen something similar before? I can't figure out what's causing this.

**Addendas:

Session configuration**

```
'session' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\DbSession',
    'name' => 'sess',
    'timeout' => 3600,
    'db' => 'session_db',
    'sessionTable' => 'session', 
],
```

Session db config

```
$config['components']['session_db'] = [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    ...
],
```

Login action

```
// authenticate() Just checks if the user is valid, etc
Yii::$app->user->authenticate();

// login() just calls parent::login(), sets some session values then returns !$this->getIsGuest()
Yii::$app->user->login(Yii::$app->user);
```

**update!!** I have just noticed that if I use the same database instead of "db" (my main db) instead of "session_db", it works perfectly, even if both tables have exactly the same schema in the 2 databases.

Comment: How did you configured this session component? Do you use transactions somewhere? How your login action looks like?

Comment: I added lots of info that I hope might be useful. I don't know what transactions are so I guess I'm not using any

Comment: Check my latest update, I just found a good clue, however I still don't get it

Comment: @user2593609 did u get this working? i can't get mine to work